# How do you create a turning algorithm in python that sends to an Arduino?

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial

I am working on a project that sends a set of instructions (pitch, roll, and yaw) to an Arduino using pyserial. With these instructions, I want to send them in a manner of turning to the given points, rather than setting the placement to them. Currently, I'm just updating the Arduino with the newly set instructions, but would prefer them to be sent in smoothly so any adjustments between previous and new instructions are not abrupt. How would I do this? Below is the relevant section of code that sends the instructions to the Arduino.

```
     newPitch = round(pitch * RAD_TO_DEG, 1)
     newYaw = round(yaw * RAD_TO_DEG, 1)
     newRoll = round(roll * RAD_TO_DEG, 1)

     flightTuple = (0, int(newPitch), int(newYaw), int(newRoll), 1)
     write_read(flightTuple)

def write_read(x):
     print x
     arduino.write(bytearray(str(x), 'utf-8'))
     time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! You're question is a little unclear. Can you tell us what specifically your algorithm needs to do, as in give us the desired input and output? Is there anything in the code that you're struggling with specifically, such as any errors? How would you go about doing what you're asking for on paper? I fear if we don't narrow your question down a bit then it won't be on topic here!

Comment: You could use `numpy.linespace` to go from the current value to the desired value smoothly.

Comment: @Guimoute that's "`linspace`" ("linear space"), not "`linespace`".

Comment: Hi Ari! Maybe algorithm was the wrong word, but basically I want to pass the pitch, roll, and yaw to the Arduino without a sudden jump in one of them causing an abrupt shift to the Arduino. My code currently works fine, I just want to proof it for fast movement if possible, and I'm struggling to think of how I would do that as I pass the information to the Arduino.

Comment: You need to break down the information into smaller bits. Instead of sending "90°" once, you would send <current angle>, ..., ..., 75, 80, 85, 90 with a step size and sleeping time between orders that results in a smooth enough and fast enough movement.

Comment: "Algorithm" is the correct word. Your application is where [PID](https://github.com/br3ttb/Arduino-PID-Library/) (read the associated article which is linked by the github library) can be applied. For python, there is a [simple-pid](https://pypi.org/project/simple-pid/) that you could use.